# Recursively trying to find the maximum w/o loops

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.7

So I'm given a tuple of ordered pairs in this format:

`(x,y)` where
x represents the physical weight of the objects, y represents the cost/value of the object.

```
((5, 20), (10, 70), (40, 200), (20, 80), (10, 100))
```

Objects may only be used once, but there may be multiples of those objects in the original tuple of ordered pairs.

z is the max weight that can be shipped. It's an integer. z could be 50 or something like that.

Goal: Find the maximum value possible that you can send given the limit Z.

The difficulty is that we can ONLY use recursion and we cannot use loops nor can we use python built-in functions.

I've tried to work out the max value in a list of integers, which I did separately to try to get some sort of idea. I have also tried giving the objects a 'mass' and doing value/weight, but that didn't work very well either.

```py
def maximum_val(objects: ((int,int),) , max_weight : int) -> int:
    if max_weight == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return objects[0][1] + maximum_val(objects[1:], max_weight - gifts[0][0])
```

```
((5, 20), (10, 70), (40, 200), (20, 80), (10, 100))
```

Example: Given the tuple above and the limit *Z=40*, the best possible value that could be obtained is ***250 -> (10, 70), (10, 100), (20, 80)***

Comment: Look up the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Here is a solution to the Knapsack problem using dynamic programming:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/20581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as knapsack and you are looking for a recursive variant.
At every step, check what is best.  Include the first object or skip the first object:

objects = ((5, 20), (10, 70), (40, 200), (20, 80), (10, 100))

```
def recursive_knapsack(objects, limit ):

    if not objects:
        return 0

    if objects[0][0] > limit:
        #first object cant fit
        return recursive_knapsack(objects[1:],limit)

    include =  objects[0][1] + recursive_knapsack(objects[1:], limit-objects[0][0])
    exclude = recursive_knapsack(objects[1:],limit)

    if include < exclude:
        return exclude
    else:
        return include
```

Comment: It was stated that max function cannot be used

Comment: It is not that hard for the OP to write a custom max function using recursion.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you Christian. I will be looking over this and Unni's explanation tonight. Appreciate the help. I'm still a noob with recursion.

If you have any tips for me I'd appreciate it!